# Adding Timestamp to JobParameter in ItemReader Spring Batch

Tags: parameters, spring-batch, sql-timestamp

Could you please help me to add a TIMESTAMP value to JobParameter in Spring Batch.

My JDBCPageItemReader is given below:

```
<bean id="beanSample"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader"
    scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="pgDataSource" />
    <property name="queryProvider">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="pgDataSource" />
            <property name="selectClause" value="SELECT *" />
            <property name="fromClause" value="FROM sh.trains" />
            <property name="whereClause" value="WHERE train_type = :train_type_inp and destination = :dest_code 
                                                and train_time between = :time_a and = :time_b" />                                   
            <property name="sortKey" value="train_time" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="parameterValues">
        <map>
            <entry key="pymt_type_code" value="#{jobParameters['train_type']}" />
            <entry key="mrkt_code" value="#{jobParameters['dest_code']}" />
            <entry key="start_time" value="#{jobParameters['time_a']}" />
            <entry key="end_time" value="#{jobParameters['time_b']}" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="pageSize" value="5" />
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="com.train.timetable.Mapper.SampleMapper" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

In the above PostgreS DB, train_time is added as type TIMESTAMP. Hence I need to add parameter time_a and time_b as JobParameter when I run the Job. But I do not understand how to add TIMESTAMP in JobParameter. I have tried by passing the time as String (as given below). But it does not work.

```
JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
            .addString("train_type", "LOCAL")
            .addString("dest_code", "CAN")
            .addString("time_a", "2018-02-05 18:21:46.24812")
            .addString("time_b", "2018-02-05 18:22:07.085596").toJobParameters();


    JobExecution result = jobLauncher.run(jobLocator.getJob(jobName), jobParameters);
```

Can anybody please help me with this. Thanks in Advance. 
I have searched about the issue and found out about DefaultJobParametersConverter class in Spring. But I am not sure how to use it. Please please help me. I am stuck here. I cannot change the Column type from TIMESTAMP.

Comment: In your case, you are using native query, so please use a function provided by postgres (in your case) to convert from String to Timestamp such as TO_TIMESTAMP. Something like .... WHERE train_time between TO_TIMESTAMP(:start_time,'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') and ....

Comment: Thanks for the response @Nghia Do,, But I am not able to use this built-in postgres function JdbcPagingItemReader. As you can see. I am using SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean for querying. 

It seems like SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean will not support postgres specific function. But when I checked, there is another query provider PostgresPagingQueryProvider. Anybody knows how to use it?

Comment: Did you try it? What error you are getting? Please post here

Comment: Hi Nghia, the function TO_TIMESTAMP did not work in my code, but it works in pgAdminIII. I am using SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean in my bean to provide query to Bean which does not support postgres Functions. Any suggestion?

Comment: Pls post error when you tried. I would like to see stack trace with error

Answer (score 0):

You Can use `addDate` method

```
parameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                           .addDate("key", new Date())
                           .toJobParameters();
```